# How can I change the format for the number displayed in google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have a code that draws the following chart:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy6us.png)

I basically made a stacked column/bar chart in Google Charts, and i want to know if is there a way to change the number format ?
this is an example of how i want the format looks like : [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px7PT.png)

here is the script where the chart is draw:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var dataE = [
        ['EMP', 'CONT', 'CRE', 'TOT', {
          role: 'annotation'
        }],
        [1, 20500, 12800, 21000, ''],

        [2, 36900, 25600, 38000, ''],

        [3, 73000, 75000, 80500, ''],

        [4, 70500, 37000, 73000, ''],

     

      ];
      var colorsE = [{
          color: '#229954'
        },
        {
          color: '#E74C3C'
        },
      ];

      function drawChartE() {
        //Set chart options

        var optionsE = {
          chartArea: {
            left: '25',
            width: '80%',
            right: '25'
          },
          title: '',
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            maxLines: 3
          },

          annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: true,
            textStyle: {
              fontSize: 13,
              color: '#000'
            }
          },
          isStacked: true,
          series: colorsE,
        };
        //Create the data table       
                
        var chartDataE = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataE);
      
        for (var ii = 0; ii < chartDataE.getNumberOfRows(); ii++) {
          var totalE = 0;
          for (var jj = 1; jj < chartDataE.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; jj++) {
            //console.log(chartData.getValue(i, j));
            totalE += chartDataE.getValue(ii, jj);
          }
          chartDataE.setValue(ii, chartDataE.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, '' + totalE);
        }
        //Instantiate and draw the chart....
        var chartE = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_materialE'));
        chartE.draw(chartDataE, optionsE);
      }
      //Load the API and package
      google.charts.load('visualization', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      });
      //Set a Callback
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartE);

    </script>
```

The full code for the chart is here:
[Chart code](http://jsfiddle.net/470gmfs6/72/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google's `NumberFormat` class.
in this case, it appears you want to use a "short" pattern,
which abbreviates big numbers by adding "K" for thousand, "M" for million, etc...

```
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: 'short'
    });
```

to use the number formatter, pass the number value to the `formatValue` method.

```
    formatter.formatValue(totalE)
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dataE = [
        ['EMP', 'CONT', 'CRE', 'TOT', {
          role: 'annotation'
        }],
        [1, 20500, 12800, 21000, ''],

        [2, 36900, 25600, 38000, ''],

        [3, 73000, 75000, 80500, ''],

        [4, 70500, 37000, 73000, ''],

     

      ];
      var colorsE = [{
          color: '#229954'
        },
        {
          color: '#E74C3C'
        },
      ];

      function drawChartE() {
        //Set chart options

        var optionsE = {
          chartArea: {
            left: '25',
            width: '80%',
            right: '25'
          },
          title: '',
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            maxLines: 3
          },

          annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: true,
            textStyle: {
              fontSize: 13,
              color: '#000'
            }
          },
          isStacked: true,
          series: colorsE,
        };
        //Create the data table
        
        
        
        var chartDataE = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataE);
        
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
          pattern: 'short'
        });
      
        for (var ii = 0; ii < chartDataE.getNumberOfRows(); ii++) {
          var totalE = 0;
          for (var jj = 1; jj < chartDataE.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; jj++) {
            //console.log(chartData.getValue(i, j));
            totalE += chartDataE.getValue(ii, jj);
          }
          chartDataE.setValue(ii, chartDataE.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, formatter.formatValue(totalE));
        }
        //Instantiate and draw the chart....
        var chartE = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_materialE'));
        chartE.draw(chartDataE, optionsE);
      }
      //Load the API and package
      google.charts.load('visualization', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      });
      //Set a Callback
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartE);

    </script>

    <div id="columnchart_materialE" style="width: auto;height:500px;border: 1px solid #ffffff;margin: 0px;padding: 20px;"></div>



  </body>

</html>
```